# basic python syntax that i don't quite get

Tags: python, api, syntax

I keep getting this error, I'm not sure why though.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cambria/Main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from RiotAPI import RiotAPI
  File "/home/cambria/RiotAPI.py", line 6
    def __init__(self, api_key, region=Consts.REGIONS['north_america'])
                                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have not used Python for that long, I am just using it because it facilitates what I'm trying to do well, but I have used various other languages and as far as I can tell you would want to close these `()'s` in this statement `def __init__(self, api_key, region=Consts.REGIONS['north_america'])` however I keep getting a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`?

the rest of that definition is as follows, if it helps.

```
class RiotAPI(object):
    def __init__(self, api_key, region=Consts.REGIONS['north_america'])
        self.api_key = api_key
        self.region = region
```

EDIT 1: if i add a `:` at the end of `def __init__(self, api_key, region=Consts.REGIONS['north_america']):` like so, why? and after doing this i get a new syntax error that i will address after some wisedom

EDIT 2: new syntax error after fixing the first is,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cambria/Main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from RiotAPI import RiotAPI
  File "/home/cambria/RiotAPI.py", line 11
    args = ('api_key': self.api_key)
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

which is

```
def _request(self, api_url, params=()):
    args = ('api_key': self.api_key)
    for key, value in params.items():
        if key not in args:
            args[key] = value
```

EDIT 3: This should be the last of it.. no more syntax, just a

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cambria/Main.py", line 10, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/cambria/Main.py", line 5, in main
    respons3 = api.get_summoner_by_name('hi im gosan')
  File "/home/cambria/RiotAPI.py", line 31, in get_summoner_by_name
    return self._request(api_url)
  File "/home/cambria/RiotAPI.py", line 12, in _request
    for key, value in params.items():
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'items'
```

in

```
def _request(self, api_url, params=()):
        args = {'api_key': self.api_key}
        for key, value in params.items():
            if key not in args:
                args[key] = value
        response = requests.get(
            Consts.URL['base'].format(
                proxy=self.region,
                region=self.region,
                url=api_url
                ),
            params=args
            )
        print response.url
        return response.json()
```

this is the only error i have received that i really don't know much on. Is this a result of there being no `.items` on my params? or i left it initialized as an empty dictionary?

Comment: what is the new syntax error?

Comment: thanks for helping @JamesAndariese ive updated my question in Edit 2. is the ':' used to end statements or to 'block' it in with the code its refering to?

Comment: VERY SORRY ALL FOR MY FORMAT :( english is second language and first time here! thank you for understanding

Comment: For your edit 2, youy're trying to create a dictionary with `()` instead of `{}`.

Comment: ah i see, i have changed them to {} and its fine, however i'm now recieving a tuple error somewhere that i'm not indexing..

Comment: You define `params` as a tuple and a tuple does not have an `items` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is just that you're missing a : at the end of the line.

```
def __init__(self, api_key, region=Consts.REGIONS['north_america']):
    self.api_key = api_key
    self.region = region
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a `:`:

```
class RiotAPI(object):
    def __init__(self, api_key, region=Consts.REGIONS['north_america']): # <HERE
        self.api_key = api_key
        self.region = region
```